# How to set a number range validation in html.textboxfor in cshtml view page in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PercentNos, new {@class = "percentage-numbers"})
```

How to set the numbers limit 0 to 100 in `@html.textboxfor` in cshtml view page in mvc4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Range attribute to limit the input from 0 to 100. You apply this attribute to the (target) property of the model you are using in your view.

```
[Range(0,100)]
public int PercentNos { get; set; }
```