# Html.TextBoxFor only accepting a number greater than zero

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I've made an form and I want the `@Html.TextBoxFor` to accept values equal or higher than `1`. That means: the value can't be 0 or lower.

**Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "//")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{1,3}$", ErrorMessage = "//")]
public string Time { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Time)
```

Can I do this with a DataAnnotation, or is there an other way?

Comment: If you want a number with a minimum value of 1, then your property need to be a numeric type (say `int`) not a `string`, and you apply a `[Range]` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke You don't have a textbox special for numbers. There is no way like `type="number"`.

Comment: Yes, you can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Duur, new { type = "number", @class = "form-control" ... })` if you want to use the browsers HTML5 number control

Comment: But its not really necessary. If a non-numeric character was entered, you would immediately get a validation message that its not valid

Comment: And than change it to:`public int Duur { get; set; }`?

Comment: Yes, and add `[Range(1, 999, `ErrorMessage = "The number must between 1 and 999")]` (or what ever the max value you want is)

Comment: Works! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a number range validation in html.textboxfor in cshtml view page in mvc4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394011/how-to-set-a-number-range-validation-in-html-textboxfor-in-cshtml-view-page-in-m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works when you place `[Range(beginnumber, endnumber)]` above the property in the Model.

```
[Range(1, 1000)]
public int Time { get; set; }
```

The textbox needs to be of the type number. That is possible by adding `type = "number"` to the html element.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Time, null, new { type = "number"})
```

---

Answer through commands from [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
<input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10">
```

in Razor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TicketID, null, new { @min="0" , @max="10" , type = "range", @class = .....})
```

Comment: Bear in mind this is only [supported on IE 10 or greater](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-range)